# SEO text in hidden element

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, css, seo, google

I have created a small extension in Magento 1.9 latest which gives me the ability to insert text for SEO purposes on every category page.
I have made this in frontend hidden with CSS.
But as I read Google isn't reading this "hidden" content and sometimes sees this as spam.

What is the best way to use this text in the right way?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is to ensure the text is indeed relevant and visible for the users, otherwise it will be seen as less relevant and possible spam. Technique you describe was effective years ago, but search engines got smarter